# Passing an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Why is the output for the following code `11,21,31 11,21,31` and not `10,20,30 10,20,30`?

```
public class Tp {

    public static void doChange(int a[])
    {
        for(int pos=0;pos<a.length;pos++)
        {
            a[pos]+=1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[]= {10,20,30};
        doChange(arr);
        for(int x:arr)
        {
            System.out.print(x+",");
        }

        System.out.println(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]+" "+arr[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it be either? Surely it is [`11,21,31,11 21  31`](https://ideone.com/xt9grA)?

Comment: Because you modify the **content** of the array, not the array itself. The array itself is still the same on return.

Comment: this is clear. you write a[pos]+=1;, that is equal to a[pos] = a[pos] + 1. So you take the content and increment by 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: `int a[]` is just like reference to `arr` array.So calling of method `doChange` is just like call by reference

Comment: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Because in java arrays are objects, when you pass the `arr` array to the `doChange()` method as argument, it actually copies the reference id of that array (not the elements).

In a simple way, you are updating the same array that you passed in the `doChange()` method, that's why it reflects to the original array.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
public static void doChange(int a[])    
{    
   for(int pos=0;pos<a.length;pos++)
   {
      a[pos]+=1;
   }
}
```

This line `a[pos]+=1;`, adds +1 to each value on the array, so the expect output is `11,21,31 11,21,31`, if you want `10,20,30 10,20,30`, delete or comment this line `doChange(arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it prints `"11, 21, 31, 11,21,31"`, with the method `doChange` you add 1 to every element of the array.

Writing:

```
a[pos]+=1;
```

is the same as writing:

```
a[pos]=a[pos]+1;
```

Answer (score -1):

`int arr[]= {10,20,30};` Initializes array `[0]=10`, `[1]=20`, `[2]=30`

`doChange` called with `a[]` which is a reference of `arr[]`

for-loop adds +1 to every value in `arr[]`  ( `+=` is equal to `x = x + ?` )

Now you have `[0]=11`, `[1]=21`, `[2]=31`